# How do I create a drop down list using angular inside CSHTML?

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-mvc

How do I create a drop down select list using angular inside CSHTML?  I tried the below two options but neither work.
Option #1

```
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="customers">Customer</label>
                <input id="{{customer.CustomerProfileId}}" ng-model="filter.customers" type="text" class="form-control selected" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

Option #2

```
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="customers">Customer2</label>
            <select id="{{customer.CustomerProfileId}}" ng-model="filter.customers" ng-options="for customer in filter.customers" type="text" class="form-control">{{customer.CustomerName}}</select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Revision #2: Thanks to your help this version is definitely a lot closer. Most of it all works except I'm not capturing the CustomerProfileId in the customerChange event. How can I identify the customerID selected?

```
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="customers">Customer</label>
                    <select class="form-control" ng-model="parameters.AvaliableCustomers" ng-change="customerChange(c.CustomerProfileId)" ng-options="c.CustomerName for c in parameters.AvaliableCustomers track by c.CustomerProfileId">
                        <option value="">-- Select --</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
```

JS Code:

```
    $scope.customerChange = function (customerId) {
        var temp = customerId;
    }
```

Comment: Can you share the Javascript code and explain which Angular's version are you using?

Comment: Is this AngularJs? Not Angular?

Comment: This is angular

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1:**

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Gender, new List<SelectListItem>(), new { @class = "form-control", @ng_model = "gender", @ng_options = "item as item.name for item in genders track by item.value" })
```

**Option 2:**

```
<select name="Gender" ng-options="item as item.name for item in genders track by item.value" ng-model="gender"></select>
```

***.js**

```
$scope.genders =
[
    { value: "M", name: "Male" },
    { value: "F", name: "Female" }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<select formControlName="countryControl" [(ngModel)]="filter.customers">
   <option [value]="customer.CustomerProfileId" *ngFor="let customer of filter.customers">             {{customer.CustomerName}}</option>
 </select>
```